# Eyes/ Double Transform

Tags: rigging

When i translate the Torso/Root controller, the eye look at works as it should but the individual eye targets inherit double transform, which result in eyes facing in another direction.

How do i fix this?
[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand. could you post a .blend?

Comment: You have a bone in between the eyes that gets left behind after you moved the rig, shouldn't it be parented to another bone to move with them?

Comment: Thanks Sambler. I overlooked the parenting of the minds eye (the parent of the two individual eyes). Minds eye was not parented to the head deformation bone which was causing the problem. Its fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

As Chetan Trivedi said:

> .. . I overlooked the parenting of the minds eye (the parent of the two individual eyes). Minds eye was not parented to the head deformation bone which was causing the problem. Its fixed now.

*Posted to take this off of the un-answered list*